# Props undefined inside state of child component

Tags: reactjs

I am following a react tutorial in which the author is passing data from the counters component to the child counter component.

Counters component:

```
class Counters extends Component {
    state = { counters:[
        {id:1,value:4},
        {id:2,value:0},
        {id:3,value:0},
        {id:4,value:0}
    ] } 
    render() { 
        return (
            <div>
              {this.state.counters.map(c=>(
                <Counter key={c.id} value={c.value} selected={true}/>
              ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
Counter component:
class Counter extends Component {
    state={
        value:this.props.value
    }
    render() { 
        console.log("props",this.props)
        return (
            <div>
                <span  className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
                <button onClick={this.handleIncrement} className="btn btn-secondary>Increment</button>
            </div>
        );
```

this.props is not undefined inside the render function but for some reason it is undefined when I use it in the  state it gives me:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value').I don't know why this is happening.The same code works fine in the tutorial

Comment: This may be happening, because `this.props` isn't available when the `state` object in the `<Counter />` is being initialized. You can move the initialization of the state to the `constructor()` of the component and use props passed in constructor instead of `this.props` in state initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
        value: this.props.value
    };
}
```

Thanks